# Excel Pivot Table - show additional info about rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a large table/data set (30k rows and growing). It lists individual actions taken on a wide range of documents.

Each document resides in a site and in a library within that site. I need to provide a report showing the top 10 documents across all libraries per site, for the previous 3 months.

This is what the requestor sent. 
[image]

I can get 90% of this with a pivot table and a slicer. 
[image]

What I need to figure out is how to display the library associated with each document.

In response to the commenter: If I use this pivot table setup, I get the list of documents desired. What I can't figure out is how to display the Library column without grouping the results by library.

[image]

Comment: Well, you've confused me because you say, "*Each document resides in a site and in a library within that site.*" and you post a picture of a table with a 1 library per document..... so if you have data to build the table, what's the problem keeping you from loading it into the pivot?

Comment: I've updated the question with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

*[...] the top 10 documents across all libraries* **per site,** *[...]*

You're grouping by site, so it should be the first field in the rows box.  You're also listing every library per site, so library is the second field in the rows box.  Document is the third field in the rows box.  Date goes in the columns box.

You have some options for the top 10 action counts.  You can use built in filters or calculated fields.

The table you posted does not reflect the conditions but you can match the format with two simple changes in the Pivot Table options, set the table to tabular and turn on repeated rows.